# Having an Issue creating a one to many relation using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, partial-views, one-to-many

I've seen many questions on this being asked but I can't find one that helps me, I trying to create a one to many relation between buildings and rooms i.e one building with many rooms. As far as I can tell my ICollection<> value isn't being sent to my database. I'm using a partial view to create rooms inside of a building, my buildings model contains the Icollection and my rooms model contains the building Id. However when I create a room it doesn't connect the buildingId with the ICollection<> value.

Here are my models for both the buildings and the rooms:

```
public class buildingInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int buildingNumber { get; set; }
    public String buildingName { get; set; }
    public String buildingAddress { get; set; }
    public String buildingDesc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<roomInfo> curRooms { get; set; }
}

public class roomInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    public String roomName { get; set; }
    public String roomLocation { get; set; }
    public String roomDesc { get; set; }
    public int buildingId { get; set; }
}
```

This the rooms view:

```
 @model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h3>Rooms in: @Model.buildingName</h3>
<ol class="round">

<li class="one">
    <h5>Please begin creating your network structure:</h5> <button id="modal-opener">Add a new room</button>

</li>
</ol>

@Html.Partial("rooms", Model.curRooms)

<div id="Modal" title="Room Details">
    @Html.Partial("roomForm", new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo { buildingId =  Model.Id })
</div>
```

Here is the form that takes in the room details:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("roomForm","Home"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>roomInfo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Room Number:")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.roomNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.roomNumber)
    </div>
    ....
    <div style="visibility: hidden">

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.buildingId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingId)
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
 }
 @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

And these are the methods handling the rooms partial view:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult roomForm(int buildingId)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    //Here the data from the room form is inserted to the database
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult roomForm(roomInfo roominfo)
    {
        //roominfo.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.rooms.Add(roominfo);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("room", new {id = roominfo.buildingId});
        }

        return PartialView(roominfo);
    }
```

Here is the DBContext:

```
public class thDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<buildingInfo> buildings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<roomInfo> rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<deviceInfo> devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<rackInfo> rackInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

If any further info is required please ask.

Comment: Your buildinginfo class should have a constructor initialising a list of roomInfo.

curRooms = new List<roomInfo>();

Comment: Like this:  public List<roomInfo> curRooms = new List<roomInfo>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Entity Framework cannot identify the correct foreign key between your entities by its conventions because your property naming conventions do not match anything EF expects. Likely it's adding its own foreign key so when you set buildingId on the roomInfo entity it isn't being treated as a foreign key.

You can try adding some entity mapping configuration in your DbContext to explicitly describe the relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<buildingInfo>().HasMany(b=>b.curRooms).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(r=>r.buildingId);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I implemented you code: 
     
     The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.DependentNavigationPropertyConfiguration<TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo>.HasForeignKey<TKey>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo,TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: That's what I get for writing code in a web page text field. ;) Check the updated code in the answer above.

Comment: it worked! I've been stuck on this for days. Could I replicate this one to many for racks within rooms?

Comment: Yes you can. In my opinion it's a good idea to write code like the above to explicitly describe every relationship between entities instead of trying to rely on conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
public class buildingInfo
{

    public buildingInfo()
    {
        curRooms = new List<roomInfo>();

    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int buildingNumber { get; set; }
    public String buildingName { get; set; }
    public String buildingAddress { get; set; }
    public String buildingDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<roomInfo> curRooms { get; set; }
}

public class roomInfo
{

    public roomInfo()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    public String roomName { get; set; }
    public String roomLocation { get; set; }
    public String roomDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual buildingInfo BuildingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I put in the code and I tried to update the package manager but it gave me this back:The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'buildingId' on type 'TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo' is not valid. The navigation property 'buildingInfo' was not found on the dependent type 'TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Comment: I was explicitly setting the foriegn key when i didnt really need to. See update. Ive tested this and it is working fine